# private abstract classes in Java

Tags: java, class, private, abstract

I am a relative newcomer to Java. I recently came across a private static abstract class inside a regular class while browsing some Android app source code. What could be a use case for such a nested class? How would it be used and what sort of design benefits are there from using such a class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've never come across this pattern before myself, but I can imagine it being useful if:

- You want to implement an interface in a similar way in a bunch of nested classes (e.g. to be returned from public methods within the enclosing class)
- Those interface implementations have a lot of code in common (hence the abstract class)
- You don't need any code *other* than the implementations to know about the abstract class

The subclasses of the abstract class may well be private as well. (Typically when I write nested classes, they're private implementation details.) For example:

```
public interface Foo {
    // Methods here
}

public class FooFactory {

    public static Foo getFoo1() {
        return new Foo1();
    }

    public static Foo getFoo2() {
        return new Foo2();
    }

    private static abstract class AbstractFoo implements Foo {
        // Implement methods in Foo in terms of 
        // doSomething()...

        // Implementation-specific method
        public abstract void doSomething();
    }

    private static class Foo1 extends AbstractFoo {
        public void doSomething() {
        }
    }

    private static class Foo2 extends AbstractFoo {
        public void doSomething() {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What could be a use case for such a nested class?

You would use this if:

- you were going to implement a number of nested classes with common functionality, and
- you didn't want the base class with that functionality to be visible.

You would probably also make the leaf classes either `final` or `private`.

> How would it be used and what sort of design benefits are there from using such a class?

See above.  Basically, you are hiding the class so that it cannot be directly subclassed outside of the outermost enclosing class.  I think this will also prevent the subclasses from being used polymorphically outside of the outermost enclosing class.

This is not a common use-case, but I imagine it is sensible in the context that you found it.

Answer (score 0):

A typical use is to replace the equivalent of a C struct - for instance a small class that contains a name and a value and gets stored in a List or Map in the enclosing class. Because it is not used outside of the compilation unit, it can be private.

The static keyword usage is a bit odd here; all it means is that the class has no connection with the enclosing class.

Making it abstract is unusual - it indicates that there will be concrete implementations and I have never done that. YMMV...

Comment: Why would a name/value pair be abstract?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a nested class is to clearly group the nested class with its surrounding class, signaling that these two classes are to be used together.

Nested classes are considered members of their enclosing class. Thus, a nested class can be declared public, package (no access modifier), protected and private (see access modifiers for more info).
Static Nested Classes

Static nested classes are declared like this:

```
public class Outer {

  public static class Nested {

  }

}
```

In order to create an instance of Nested you must reference it by prefixing it with the Outer class name, like this:

`Outer.Nested instance = new Outer.Nested();`

A static nested class is essentially a normal class that has just been nested inside another class. It interacts with its enclosing class in the same way. Being static, a static nested class can only access instance variables of the enclosing class via a reference to an instance of the enclosing class.

Comment: This is all good information, but I don't think it answers the question.